# data fitting delphi7 component

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

is there any   data fitting component for delphi7 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can find a lot of information about algorithms in Delphi on [efg's Delphi Reference Library](http://www.efg2.com/Lab/Library/Delphi/index.html). For data fitting for example take a look at section Numerical methods.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at: http://jedimath.sourceforge.net/